# Deprecated APIs when trying to migrate cluster to v1.22

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, fabric8

I attempted to migrate my cluster and I get the `Migrate to updated APIs to upgrade to v1.22.` error in GCP Control Panel:
[GCP Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LbKn.png)

It list that I have called the following APIs:

```
/apis/networking.k8s.io/v1beta1/ingresses
/apis/extensions/v1beta1/ingresses
/apis/networking.k8s.io/v1beta1/ingressclasses
/apis/admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1beta1/validatingwebhookconfigurations
```

But the last time I called them was 2 days ago which is when I started attempting to upgrade and I have removed references to them in my terraform scripts.

I have ran `kubent` and this is the output from it:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/kubent
11:03AM INF >>> Kube No Trouble `kubent` <<<
11:03AM INF version 0.5.1 (git sha )
11:03AM INF Initializing collectors and retrieving data
11:03AM INF Target K8s version is 1.22.8-gke.202
11:03AM INF Retrieved 161 resources from collector name=Cluster
11:03AM INF Retrieved 0 resources from collector name="Helm v2"
11:03AM INF Retrieved 19 resources from collector name="Helm v3"
11:03AM INF Loaded ruleset name=custom.rego.tmpl
11:03AM INF Loaded ruleset name=deprecated-1-16.rego
11:03AM INF Loaded ruleset name=deprecated-1-22.rego
11:03AM INF Loaded ruleset name=deprecated-1-25.rego
__________________________________________________________________________________________
>>> Deprecated APIs removed in 1.22 <<<
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
KIND                       NAMESPACE     NAME                                           API_VERSION                    REPLACE_WITH (SINCE)
CustomResourceDefinition   <undefined>   capacityrequests.internal.autoscaling.k8s.io   apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1   apiextensions.k8s.io/v1 (1.16.0)
CustomResourceDefinition   <undefined>   globalbgpconfigs.crd.projectcalico.org         apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1   apiextensions.k8s.io/v1 (1.16.0)
CustomResourceDefinition   <undefined>   globalfelixconfigs.crd.projectcalico.org       apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1   apiextensions.k8s.io/v1 (1.16.0)
CustomResourceDefinition   <undefined>   scalingpolicies.scalingpolicy.kope.io          apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1   apiextensions.k8s.io/v1 (1.16.0)
Ingress                    elastic       kibana-kibana                                  networking.k8s.io/v1beta1      networking.k8s.io/v1 (1.19.0)
__________________________________________________________________________________________
>>> Deprecated APIs removed in 1.25 <<<
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
KIND                  NAMESPACE     NAME                       API_VERSION      REPLACE_WITH (SINCE)
PodDisruptionBudget   elastic       elasticsearch-master-pdb   policy/v1beta1   policy/v1 (1.21.0)
PodSecurityPolicy     <undefined>   gce.gke-metrics-agent      policy/v1beta1   <removed> (1.21.0)
```

As far as I can tell those APIs aren't used anywhere in my code. The only reference to them that I can find is in a jar for the `fabric8` dependency. They have kept both `v1beta1` and the new `v1` for backward compatibility.

Is it possible since that's in the jar for the dependency to be preventing me from upgrading, even tho I am not using it? If that's the case is there anything I can do to upgrade the version?

Answer (score 5):

I have the same issue with migration to 1.22.

I've taken a look from the object browser in GCP.

`capacityrequests.internal.autoscaling.k8s.io` contains metadata apiVersion for both `v1beta1` and the new `v1`. I think this might be why Kubent marks this as deprecated.

However, in the GCP warning, this API is not mentioned, so I guess GCP does not count this.